# Log Query Alert Example

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-bicep, azure-alerts, azure-sentinel

I am designing a monitoring solution for a project and would like to create some alert rules for certain resources (for example application insights).

If I'd like to set up a log search alert, I need to define a specific query and tell the alert what to do.

However, I have not written a log query alert before and do not know how I could set that up.
Currently, I have written an example for a log search in Bicep:

```
@description('Location of the resource.')
param location string

@description('Log Analytics workspace ID to associate with your Application Insights resource.')
param workspaceId string

@allowed([
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4])
  @description('Severity of the alert.')
  param severity int = 2

resource appInsightsLogRule 'Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules@2022-06-15' = {
  name: appInsightsLogRuleName
  location: location
  properties: {
    displayName: appInsightsLogRuleName
    severity: severity
    enabled: true
    evaluationFrequency: 'PT5M'
    scopes: [
      workspaceId
    ]
    targetResourceTypes: [
      'Microsoft.Insights/components'
    ]
    windowSize: 'PT5M'
    criteria: {
      allOf: [
        {
          query: 'tbd.'
          timeAggregation: 'Count'
          dimensions: []
          operator: 'GreaterThan'
          threshold: 0
          failingPeriods: {
            numberOfEvaluationPeriods: 1
            minFailingPeriodsToAlert: 3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    autoMitigate: true
    actions: {
      actionGroups: [
        actiongroups_team_blue
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query is currently still empty, as I don't know how I could fill this one.

Could someone maybe please share samples or queries for a useful scenario (for example Application Insights, Network Watcher, Sentinel, etc.) for a scheduledQueryAlert or general alert rule? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, Check the `parameter.json` file to avoid these kind of empty output issues and check whether the given query is valid.*

[Referring to MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/resource-manager-alerts-log?tabs=bicep), *I tried to create a sample scheduled log alert for log analytics workspace  resource and verify that it was sent to the given email address. It worked and was successfully deployed as follows.*

```bash
@description('Log Analytics workspace Resource ID.')
param  sourceId  string = ''
param  location  string = ''
param  actionGroupId  string = ''
resource  logQueryAlert  'Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules@2018-04-16' = {
name: 'xxxxx log query alert'
location: location
properties: {
description: 'This is a sample alert'
enabled: 'true'
source: {
query: 'Event | where EventLevelName == "warning" | summarize count() by Computer' #query as per the requirement
dataSourceId: sourceId
queryType: 'ResultCount'
}
schedule: {
frequencyInMinutes: 15
timeWindowInMinutes: 60
}
action: {
'odata.type': 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction'
severity: '4'
aznsAction: {
actionGroup: array(actionGroupId)
emailSubject: 'xxxx Log Alert mail subject'
customWebhookPayload: '{ "alertname":"#samplealertrulename", "IncludeSearchResults":true }'
}
trigger: {
thresholdOperator: 'GreaterThan'
threshold: 1
}
}
}
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

*Azure Portal:*

[image]

***Log query alert:***

[image]

***Mail triggered successfully:***

[image]